# Web API 2 Individual Accounts not working on server

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, asp.net-web-api2

When working with the new Web API 2 oauth. It works fine locally, but when published on a server it does not work. I am assuming that ASP has some sort of local DB that they store all of the accounts on and my server does not have access to this (maybe I am wrong). Has anyone ran into this issue or sure how to get this working on a server? Thanks for any help.

http://www.asp.net/vnext/overview/authentication/individual-accounts-in-aspnet-web-api#register

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a SQL Server installed on your server? If not, that should be the problem. [ASP.NET Identity](http://www.asp.net/identity), which does the authentication in the background, normally works against a SQL Server and creates its own database if you don't have done any modifications (you can change the Entity Framework context if you create your own which inherits from **IdentityDbContext**).

Have a look at your web.config file. It should have a connection string named *DefaultConnection*. This is the database ASP.NET Identity connects to. I guess that it works against a local database.

You could either install a SQL Server on your server and it should work like on your local PC or you change the connection string to another database.